# Title filtering needs to filter words like "probl*m"

Tags: discussion

OK, I understand the continual efforts to enforce clear, specific question titles, but I fail to see how this example below is any better than allowing the user to spell out the word "problem".  Can we add this garbage to the title filtering as well?

[image]

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560596/ssl-certificate-problm-only-with-google-api

Comment: That would just result in a cat and mouse game. The filter blocks the most common case, any post circumventing the filter can be taken care of manually.

Comment: Why nobody even attempt to edit the question with a good title?

Comment: @Braiam what initiatives are there to entice people to write a reasonable title? They question will likely be answered anyway irrespective of the title...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that when they have the same problem, they should be able to easily find it?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that when they see the same question, they could find it to close it as duplicated?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that people asks less duplicates because they can find the same question they meant to ask?

Comment: Pick any of the three.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't care enough to also edit the question body, so I refrained from editing entirely.

Comment: @Braiam I think you are mixing "for greater good" with actual initiatives that drive each person's behavior. I don't see anything in your list that would make particular person more likely to produce better title.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think you are mixing in my words the "greater good" when I actually mentioned none of it. In all my statements I described only the editor and what benefits he can obtain from it.

Answer (score 2):

We don't really need to add more to this filtering.

Couple reasons:

- it is very easy to bypa$$ such fi1ters.
- (less serious) it makes easier to spot questions that explicitly ignore rules and guidance given on SO. Like in case of linked question - by looking at the title you know at least something will be missing from question - in this case error info is not there (and question likely duplicate)...